# c++ builder with SQLite: data presentation shows WIDEMEMO in DBGrid

Tags: sqlite, c++builder, dbgrid

i use C++ Builder with SQLite database. I connect with the database through DBExpress. The problem is that DBGrid shows (WIDEMEMO) in every field and not the exact values that the database has.

I dont have this problem with other databases such as Firebird for example.

Why this behaviour? am i missing something with sqlite and how can be fixed.
Do u suggest me use SQLite / Firebird or other embeded database for a small standalone application.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I am using FireDAC in Delphi and had the same problem.
I have resolved this issue by changing the dataset TWideMemoField DisplayValue property from dvClass to dvFull. Now my DBGrid works as expected.

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is old but since it doesn't have any answer selected I will throw in my two cents. I recently came across the same problem and found a solution that might work for you as well.

This problem exists in your C++ DataSet and your SQLite. As it turns out that when you have a field with no defined size especially a text field, that field will be treated like a widememo or Memo in your DBGrid. So, what you need to do is define your text field with specific numbers of characters i.e. VARCHAR(10).

That's what I did and it work for me. I am using MySQL and Delphi with DBGrid.

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem with the DBGrid.  It doesn't handle the WIDEMEMO.  See link for help with this.

[Displaying and editing MEMO fields in Delphi's TDBGrid](http://delphi.about.com/library/weekly/aa030105a.htm)